# Unable to restore windows hidden with ShowWindow

Tags: c#, powershell, pinvoke, user32

I have the following type definition in a script:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
namespace Win32
{
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
    public static class Functions
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint="ShowWindow")]
        public static extern bool SW(System.IntPtr hWnd, Win32.SW nCmdShow);
    }
    public enum SW
    {
        HIDE               = 0,
        SHOW_NORMAL        = 1,
        SHOW_MINIMIZED     = 2,
        MAXIMIZE           = 3,
        SHOW_MAXIMIZED     = 3,
        SHOW_NO_ACTIVE     = 4,
        SHOW               = 5,
        MINIMIZE           = 6,
        SHOW_MIN_NO_ACTIVE = 7,
        SHOW_NA            = 8,
        RESTORE            = 9,
        SHOW_DEFAULT       = 10,
        FORCE_MINIMIZE     = 11
    }
}
'@
```

Everything in it works, for example:

```
[Win32.Functions]::SW((Get-Process -Name powershell).MainWindowHandle, [Win32.SW]::SHOW_DEFAULT)
```

However, when I utilize `[Win32.SW]::HIDE`, I am completely unable to restore that window.  Every option fails and I get `false` returns.  Is there something I'm missing in the documentation or a feature of `SW_HIDE` that is making this impossible to restore?

*My end goal here is creating some WPF GUIs in self-expanding `.cmd`->`.ps1` scripts, creating a pseudo-executable and hiding the left-behind powershell window (maybe to be restored depending on script actions).*

Comment: What code do you use to restore your window?

Comment: @rs232 The code snippet below the main block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that **`.MainWindowHandle` is no longer valid *while the window is hidden***<sup>[1]</sup>
, so the attempt to "unhide" the window fails.

Simply *cache* the HWND and use the cached value in the "unhiding" call:

```
# Also consider Get-Process -ID $PID, as in Stanislav's answer, to avoid ambiguity 
# if multiple PowerShell processes exist.
$hWnd = (Get-Process -Name PowerShell).MainWindowHandle

# ... hide window and do stuff

# Unhide, using the *cached* HWND:
[Win32.Functions]::SW($hWnd, [Win32.SW]::SHOW_DEFAULT)
```

<sup>As an aside: The [`ShowWindow()` Windows API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) (aliased to `SW` here)
 returns a Boolean value that doesn't reflect *success*, but whether the window was previously hidden (`$False`) or not (`$True`).</sup>

---

<sup>[1] The property type is `[System.IntPtr]`, and its value is `0` while the window is hidden.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

what I can see is that you are referring to process by checking its name. This can be a bit tricky as there can be running multiple processes with the same name. So if you are about to hide current PowerShell window and you would like to have it restored later on, please refer to it by using its PID rather than name. The code which might be used as an example can be found below.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
namespace Win32
{
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
    public static class Functions
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint="ShowWindow")]
        public static extern bool SW(System.IntPtr hWnd, Win32.SW nCmdShow);
    }
    public enum SW
    {
        HIDE               = 0,
        SHOW_NORMAL        = 1,
        SHOW_MINIMIZED     = 2,
        MAXIMIZE           = 3,
        SHOW_MAXIMIZED     = 3,
        SHOW_NO_ACTIVE     = 4,
        SHOW               = 5,
        MINIMIZE           = 6,
        SHOW_MIN_NO_ACTIVE = 7,
        SHOW_NA            = 8,
        RESTORE            = 9,
        SHOW_DEFAULT       = 10,
        FORCE_MINIMIZE     = 11
    }
}
'@

. ([ScriptBlock]::Create('using namespace Win32'))

$mainWindowHandle = (Get-Process -ID $PID).MainWindowHandle
[Functions]::SW($mainWindowHandle, [SW]::HIDE)

# Sleep for 5 seconds to prove it working
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

[Functions]::SW($mainWindowHandle, [SW]::SHOW_DEFAULT)
```

Please make sure before you run it that you have at least one empty line feed after the last command otherwise it will not get executed and your windows will never pop back ;)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is not the case. There was only one process running.

Comment: Good idea to use `$PID`, and your code does work, but that's because it  uses a _saved_ HWND value, unlike the OP's code (attempting to access `.MainWindowHandle` while the window was hidden was the problem). As far as I can tell, there's no need for `. ([ScriptBlock]::Create('using namespace Win32'))` - perhaps surprisingly, simply placing `using namespace Win32` at the top, as usual, works fine, even though the type is added _below_ it.

Comment: @mklement0 That is bizarre that it can include a type that isn't defined yet.  Good to know

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: I suspect that `using namespace` doesn't actually _load_ anything - it's just syntactic sugar for shortening references to types, so it doesn't have to care at that point whether the referenced namespace exists - not being a compiled language, PowerShell can get away with this. The `. ([ScriptBlock]::Create('using namespace Win32'))` technique is an interesting one, however, because it can be used to _dynamically_ alter the implicitly used namespaces, which could be used in mock-up scenarios, for instance. Note that it doesn't work with a script-block _literal_.